# How to find the kth bit of a number in c?

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift, data-representation

So the first solution that I found for this said to do:

```
(n & ( 1 << k )) >> k
```

But I don't understand how this will work because if I have the number 11100, and I want the 2nd bit, this number & (1 << 2) will give me 100. Now, if I do this number >> 2, I will get 1, which is incorrect, since the 2nd bit of the number is 0. Shouldn't each bit shift only shift k-1?

Comment: Probably that solution just considers the lowest-value bit to be the zeroth bit.

Comment: [It is common to assign each bit a position number ranging from zero to N-1 where N is the number of bits in the binary representation used.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering)

Answer (score 1):

We have number n. May it be 1234 which is 10011010010 in binary.

`(1 << k)` shifts bits in number 1. k-times to left. In the result we've got number which has all 0's except on the k-th position, where our 1 is moved.

`&` operator is bitwise AND. So each 0 will make 0 in our original n number on all positions except k-th one. There will be this k-th bit from original number as 0&1 = 0, and 1&1 = 1.

Last resort, shifting this result k - times to right makes this very bit to appear on the begining of number, so we've got either 1 or 0 depending on what has been on k-th position.

Example calculations:

```
(10011010010 & ( 1 << 4)) >> 4
(10011010010 & 00000010000) >> 4
00000010000 >> 4
00000000001
```

So 4th bit is 1.

Comment: I didn't know that in the number 10000 1 is in the 4th bit place... oops

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, making use of logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned get_bit(unsigned k, int number) {
    return ((unsigned)number & (1U << k)) > 0;
}

int main(){

    printf("b00001010 and k = 0, result = %u\n", get_bit(0, 0xA));
    printf("b00001010 and k = 0, result = %u\n", get_bit(1, 0xA));
    printf("b00001010 and k = 0, result = %u\n", get_bit(2, 0xA));
    printf("b00001010 and k = 0, result = %u\n", get_bit(3, 0xA));
    printf("b00001010 and k = 0, result = %u\n", get_bit(4, 0xA));

    return 0;
}
```